# Does MySQL 5.0 do IPv6 well?

Tags: mysql, ipv6

I'm using 
mongrel + apache 2.2 + mod_proxy_balancer + mysql

apache2.2 is IPv6 well
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/bind.html#ipv6

Does MySQL 5.0 do IPv6 well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like it may be a work in progress still. there's a bunch of patches and bug reports for "mysql ipv6" on Google.

on the plus side, you probably DONT want your MySQL DB exposed to the internet, so you could keep it on IPv4/localhost or use sockets.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL did not gain full IPv6 support until [version 5.5.3](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ipv6-support.html).